# Is there a way to display in the RStudio console the executed line numbers from the script file?

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio Server Pro (aka Workbench) in Chrome and would like to display in the console the line numbers from the executed code in the script file. If there is a such a setting, I have so far not been able to find it. Thank you for any suggestion!

For example, in an R script I have, say, on line 70 the following code:

> 70 summary(lm_robust(y ~ x, data=DF))

and when executing that line, I get in the console:

> '> summary(lm_robust(y ~ x, data=DF))

but I would like to get something like where I see the line that was executed:

> '> **70** summary(lm_robust(y ~ x, data=DF))

Maybe the logic of the console displaying a command executed from a script doesn't lend itself to that. But I would find it helpful to see which line was executed from the script.

Comment: I think you need to add more detail to your question.  The source window always displays line numbers.  What do you want in addition to that?  Maybe show us some faked output that you'd like to be real.

Comment: added a concreted example. hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do exactly what you are asking for.

In the regular RStudio it would be possible to write an add-in that added line number comments at the end of every line in a script.  You would then see

```
> summary(lm_robust(y ~ x, data=DF)) # line 70
```

when you executed that line from the script.  I don't know if this is possible in Workbench, but I'd guess it is.

Edited to add:

Here are a couple of functions to add (or update) the line number comments, or to remove them.  To make an add-in, you need to put them in an R package and follow the instructions here:  https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_addins.html .

```
addLineNos <- function() { 
  if (!rstudioapi::isAvailable()) 
    stop("Rstudio API is not available") 
  ctxt <- rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext() 
  contents <- ctxt$contents 
  # Get a range holding every line 
  lines <- seq_along(contents) 
  rng <- Map(c, Map(c, lines, 1), Map(c, lines, nchar(contents) + 1)) 
  # Remove old line numbers 
  contents <- gsub("# line [[:digit:]]+$", "", contents) 
  # Add new ones 
  contents <- paste(contents, "# line", seq_along(contents)) 
  # Put in place 
  rstudioapi::modifyRange(rng, contents, id = ctxt$id) 
} 
 
removeLineNos <- function() { 
  if (!rstudioapi::isAvailable()) 
    stop("Rstudio API is not available") 
  ctxt <- rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext() 
  contents <- ctxt$contents 
  # Get a range holding every line 
  lines <- seq_along(contents) 
  rng <- Map(c, Map(c, lines, 1), Map(c, lines, nchar(contents) + 1)) 
  # Remove old line numbers 
  contents <- gsub(" *# line [[:digit:]]+$", "", contents) 
  # Put in place 
  rstudioapi::modifyRange(rng, contents, id = ctxt$id) 
}
```